# How to show toast message in multiple lines in a Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

I have a requirement where I need to display my toast message in multiple lines in my LWC. I tried using \n and 
 but they are not working. Please assist.

Answer (score 5):

For Multiple Lines Toast in LWC

we have to override CSS :

1. Create a CSS file and add in static resource

File Content :

.toastMessage{

```
white-space: break-spaces !important;
```

}

2. Import That static resource file in your component

import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import CUSTOMCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/{yourfileName}';

a) Define variable like : isCssLoaded = false;

3. Call it in reRenderCallback

renderedCallback(){

```
if(this.isCssLoaded) return
this.isCssLoaded = true;
loadStyle(this,CUSTOMCSS).then(()=>{
    console.log('loaded');
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log('error to load');
});
```

}

4)Create your toast message like this :

var msg = 'This is first-line \nThis is Second Line. \nThis is the third Line.';

```
const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Complete Required Fields :",
            message: msg,
            variant: "error",
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: why directly adding the mentioned css to the css file in lwc will not work?

Comment: for overriding LWC standard component CSS we need to import CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of this article on SFDC Monkey that covers this exact issue! (I've used this and it works great)

http://sfdcmonkey.com/2018/05/05/multiline-toast-message-lightning-component/

Comment: You cannot use it in LWC - cannot modify elements from shadow DOM

Comment: I am facing the same issue as I am using LWC here. @David can u suggest a way to make it work in LWC.