# Unable to set Text Alignment for lightning-input (Number) LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightninginput

I am using lightning-input of type number (LWC) and trying to have input text center aligned.

At the end,  element's class is being set to "slds-input", So I cannot use custom class to add css.

I am not able to override text-align with css mentioned below.
What am I missing? Please help.

```
<lightning-input
     type="number"
     name="inputNumber"
     class="inputNumberCenter"
     value={answer}
     onchange={handleValueChange}
     step="1">
</lightning-input>


input.slds-input {
    text-align: center
};
```

Rendered HTML
[image]

Comment: You can't do this. LWC uses a shadow DOM to prevent this type of style tampering. You'll have to write your own custom component instead.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox

Comment: Hey Sriram, you just have to override the CSS of the custom component.
For that, you have to create a CSS file upload it to static resource and import it in the LWC component using loadstyle.

FYI : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278366/how-to-show-toast-message-in-multiple-lines-in-a-lightning-web-component/331035#331035

Answer (score 2):

After spending a lot of time, the below approach got worked (which is written in connectedcallback method).

Apply `input-text-align_right` class name to `lightning-input` tag.

```
const inputAligncenter = document.createElement('style');
inputAligncenter .innerText = `.input-text-align_right input{ text-align: center!important; }`;
document.body.appendChild(inputAligncenter);
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"slds-align_absolute-center"`right afer the slds-input. If it doesn't work to add a div in top:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
 <input lightning-input ....... />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried "slds-align_absolute-center", no luck.
It works for direct html "<input>" element, its just that LWC component does not allow to override css of <input> element generated by Salesforce.